# Microsoft Windows 7 PPP initialization sends "CLIENT" expects "SERVER" response

Tags: windows-7, ppp

In Windows 7 I'm trying to set up a PPP connection over a direct serial port connection to a remote device. The documentation of the remote device (as well as the documentation I've found for the Windows PPP) indicates that the process should start with a Link Control Protocol packet, but I've discovered (by sniffing the serial line) that the PC, before doing anything else, is transmitting the string "CLIENT" once per second for up to 5 seconds. Only if the PC receives the response "SERVER" will it continue with the LCP initialization.

Does anyone know what level of system functionality is sending this CLIENT string, and how I can disable it. My remote device does not recognize this and refuses to connect based on this.

Update: I have discovered that this string is being initiated by the modem driver mdmhayes.inf as a "DialPrefix", but I have no idea how to update this driver file to eliminate this dial prefix. Thoughts?

Update: I've figured out how to get Windows to stop spitting out the "CLIENT" string (it has to do with changing the DIALPREFIX setting in the mdmhayes.inf file) but I still can't figure out how to make Windows realize it is connected and just move on with establishing the PPP connection. The modem diagnostics keep indicating that unknown strings are received so it doesn't know how to proceed. There should be some setting in the mdmhayes.inf file that tells the system not to wait for anything; it's connected to a wire and that's all that is needed. I just can't figure out what setting to use to make the modem initialization get out of the way to allow the PPP stack to take over.

Answer (score 0):

in options.ttyS0 add:

```
debug
#19200
115200
192.168.111.1:192.168.111.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
lock
auth
nodefaultroute
nocrtscts
connect /etc/ppp/msclient.sh
```

msclient.sh :

```
#!/bin/sh
read -n 5 i
echo "SERVER"
```